# make multiple api requests and returned filtered response without duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Third party API can only handle one query string at a time. So I'm trying to take the query parameter, split it into array and then make async calls.

The issue is I need to filter the final response to remove all duplicates and have a final response without any duplicates.

I've tried to push responses into an array then send that as response but I'm a bit lost at the moment.

```
    const tags = req.query.tags;
    let urls = [];
    tags.split(",").forEach(tag => {
        urls.push(`https://apicall.com/posts?tag=${tag}`);
    });
    let posts = [];
    const fetchdata = async () => {
        urls.forEach(url => {
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            posts.push(response.data.posts);
        });
    };
    ????
    // Promise.all(fetchdata()).then(data => {
           //remove duplicates
           //res.json(posts)
       });
```

The following codes returns sets of arrays which is not ideal. I need to return 1 combined response while removing duplicates:

```
const fetchdata = async tags => {
        const response = await axios.get(
            `https://apicall.com/posts?tag=${tag}`
        );
        return response.data.posts
    };

    Promise.all(
        tags.split(",").length > 1
            ? tags.split(",").map(fetchdata)
            : [fetchdata(tags)]
    ).then(data => res.json(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to use `Promise.all()` to collect all the results, flatten the array of arrays to a singleArray:

```
const tags = req.query.tags;
let urls = [];
tags.split(",").forEach(tag => {
    urls.push(`https://apicall.com/posts?tag=${tag}`);
});
Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
    return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data.posts);
})).then(results => {
    let singleArray = results.flat();

    // de-dup this array here (left to the reader to finish)

    res.json(finalResult);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The general idea is that you use `urls.map()` to return an array of promises.

You use `Promise.all()` on that array or promises to know when they are all done and to get the final array of results.

Then use `.flat()` to turn the array of arrays into a single array.

Then, they need to be de-dupped.  I'm assuming this is an array of objects, but I don't know what property in those objects is the key for de-duping.  You would have to show us what each post object has in it and what determines a dup.

---

Here's an example of how you could use a `Map` object to de-dup an array of objects.  Let's suppose that each object has a property `.id` and that's the property you want to use for de-duping so that the final array of results contains no two objects with the same `id`.

```
let tracker = new Map();
for (const post of singleArray) {
    tracker.set(post.id, post);
}
// get an array of posts from the Map object
let uniquePosts = Array.from(tracker.values());
```